# Create Rails scope comparing fields on two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I have a number of associated tables in an application

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
  belongs_to :multiple_listing_service
end

class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :zip_code
  has_one :primary_mls, through: :zip_code
end
```

I wanted to create a scope that produces all the Listings that are related to the Primary MLS for the associated House. Put another way, the scope should produce all the Listings where the multiple_listing_service_id = primary_mls.id for the associated house.

I've tried dozens of nested joins scopes, and none seem to work. At best they just return all the Listings, and normally they fail out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I'm not sure a pure scope would be the way to go. Assuming you have:

```
class MultipleListingService < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings
  has_many :zip_codes
end
```

I would go for something like:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def associated_listings
    primary_mls.listings
  end
end
```

#### Update 1

If your goal is to just get the primary listing then I would add an `is_primary` field to the `Listing`. This would be the most efficient. The alternative is a 3 table join which can work but is hard to optimize well:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :primary, -> { joins(:houses => [:zip_codes])
                      .where('zip_codes.multiple_listing_service_id = listings.multiple_listing_service_id') }
```

Comment: I have a method like that, which is fine for an instance, but I need to get an array of all the primary listings so I can generate some charts off of it. Loading everything into memory is going to take forever